# Negatively scored low quality community wiki answer is the very first answer displayed

Tags: discussion

Are community wiki answers always displayed at the top regardless of their poor score or quality?

Case in point is the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892858/34806

A moderator just turned down my custom flag, so what is the recourse here? If community wiki answers are always at the top, regardless of their poor quality and/or score, I think that is a mis-feature.

If this is a duplicate sorry, I did some searching on Google first, found nothing directly on point, and as I typed in my question nothing on point came up either. Even if it *is* a duplicate, but it is indeed the case that community wiki answers are *always* at the top, I think that policy needs to be (re)visited.

Comment: I don't see this being at the top. I see it at the top if I filter by 'active'. Either oldest or votes puts that question at its rightful place

Comment: You probably have accidentally changed answer sorting.

Comment: You've sorted your answers as "active", not as "votes".

Comment: To note: I voted to close as no longer reproducible. I don't think is a duplicate issue from the way it is asked.

Comment: @TravisJ every one of the "why are these answers sorted wrong" questions end up closed as a dup of that target.  My logic on this specific question is this is an X-Y problem.  The OP thought he had problem X and wanted to ask about it.  But the answer is problem Y

Comment: @psubsee2003 - That's fine, and apparently your instinct was an accurate assumption as well.

Comment: Also: setting an answer as CW is more likely to be done by mistake than deliberately; if the question isn’t already set to CW then it can only be done for answers, by the answer owner. It’s never *abusive* to do so, which is why your flag was declined.

Comment: I'm sorry that the UI confused you, but I would have declined your flag as well, given that it was based on several incorrect assumptions. However, after reviewing that answer in the context of the question, it is obvious that it has almost nothing to do with the question and is of irredeemably low quality, so I have deleted it. Others have already pointed out that either pagination or sort order was the reason it appeared at the top, not CW status, and also that CW status is not a privilege that can be abused. It just relinquishes ownership of the answer to the community.

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be confused here, it isn't showing at the top of the list when using the default (votes) sort. However, it is the first of page 2, which is just an artifact of the paging process. The link you show takes me to page 2, where it is the top. Page 1 has the top voted answer in the #1 spot.

Didn't the moderator also inform you of this in their declined note?

Just to be clear:

> Are community wiki answers always displayed at the top

No, being a community wiki has no bearing on an answers position in the list.

Comment: Ok for some reason I must not be using the default sort.  Nevertheless this poor quality negative score answer certainly should not be a community wiki answer IMO

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - All community wiki means is that the majority editor is the name displayed, and no reputation is associated with the post. It doesn't necessarily represent the community. At least it carries the same vote count as one would expect from a poor quality answer.